# How to run multiple methods parallely and get outputs from each of them in java

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, completable-future, callable

I want to run three different methods in parallel to improve the performance in Java. Also I need to get the outputs from all the three of them. Below is the sample which I have tried. here, I'm not sure how to retrieve the returned string values. Please help me to add(concatenate all the three strings to total).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String total = "";

        Callable<String> callable1 = new Callable<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception
            {
                String t1 = "";
                t1 = method1();
                return t1;
            }
        };

        Callable<String> callable2 = new Callable<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception
            {
                String t2 = method2();
                return t2;
            }
        };

        Callable<String> callable3 = new Callable<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception
            {
                String t3 = method3();
                return t3;
            }
        };

        List<Callable<String>> taskList = new ArrayList<Callable<String>>();
        taskList.add(callable1);
        taskList.add(callable2);
        taskList.add(callable3);

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

        try
        {
            executor.invokeAll(taskList);
            //total = ;(want to concatenate all the strings here).

            System.out.println(total);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie)
        {
            //do something if you care about interruption;
        }

    }
    public static String method1()
    {
        System.out.println("method1");
        return "1";

    }

    private static String method2()
    {
        System.out.println("method2");
        return "2";
    }

    private static String method3()
    {
        System.out.println("method3");
        return "3";
    }


}
```

Comment: Try this article and the open-source it references:http://www.coopsoft.com/ar/ForkJoinArticle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `taskList` is a `List<Callable<String>>`, `executor.invokeAll(taskList)` returns a `List<Future<String>>` containing a `Future<String>` corresponding to each task in `taskList`.  You need to save that `List<Future<String>>` so that you can later get at the results of your tasks.  Something like this:

```
List<Future<String>> futureList = executor.invokeAll(tasklist);
String result = futureList.get(0).get() +
                futureList.get(1).get() +
                futureList.get(2).get();
```

In addition to `InterruptedException`, `Future.get()` can also throw `CancellationException` and `ExecutionException` so you need to be prepared to deal with these in your `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

As you have very few number of task, you can create 3 `CompletableFutures` and stream over it and join it.

```
CompletableFuture<String> task1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> method1());
CompletableFuture<String> task2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> method2());
CompletableFuture<String> task3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> method3());

String concate = Stream.of(task1, task2, task3)
        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
        .reduce("", (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2);
System.out.println(concate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on top of @Govinda answer -
You can create `Stream` of `CompletableFuture`s by using the `supplyAsync` factory method and *complete* them by calling `CompletableFuture::join` and concat by calling `Collectors.joining()`.

```
CompletableFuture<String> task1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Test::method1);      
CompletableFuture<String> task2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Test::method2);      
CompletableFuture<String> task3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Test::method3);      
                                                                                              
String concat =                                                                               
    Stream.of(task1, task2, task3).map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(concat);
```